# Spring Boot Tomcat Access logs to Cloudwatch Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to send spring boot access logs to Cloud watch in a different log group, I am using docker.
Application logs are written by default in STD OUT and are currently going to cloud watch using awsdriver.
By Default access logs are written to a file inside docker container.
How to send with file to cloud watch ?

Answer (score 0):

Using AWS log driver it will only send the logs that you sent to **stdout or stderr**, you can not send logs from file unless you change the `entrypoint` or `CMD`.

[image]

one way to send file logs to std can be

```
CMD nohup java -jar /opt/spring-cloud/lib/config-client.jar >/dev/null 2>&1 & sleep 10 && tail -f /var/log/access.log
```

**But, this is very important to know that container will still running if your spring application dies as the main process is `tail -f /var/log/access.log`,**

I will recommend writing all logs to stdout and stderr.

Another option is to mount `log` file to host, and then use cloud agent start to push logs from the mount files using [cloud watch log agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html).
[image]